# SQL Server restore from a single transaction log backup file

Tags: sql-server, transactions, backup, restore

Restoring from a single transaction log backup, containing multiple backups.  Currently using restore by specifying FILE in order.

```
RESTORE LOG db from DISK='c:\trans.bak' WITH NORECOVERY, FILE=1;
RESTORE LOG db from DISK='c:\trans.bak' WITH RECOVERY, FILE=2;
```

The above approach works.  Is it possible to restore each sequence automatically with a single RESTORE and let SQL server process them in order?  Or is there another way to handle restoring all of the backups contained in the single transaction file?

Not using different file names for log backups because there are many databases and 4 transaction backups through the day (yes I know about the risk of corrupt files, please no lectures).  I want to minimize o/s file naming/creating/checking/processing etc. at both backup and restore time,  and I'm looking for a way to manage and automate restores.

(Windows Server 2019, SQL Server 2016, Full recovery)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an out-of-the-box way that I know of. However, there is a fairly simple way with the open source dbatools powershell module.

```
Get-DbaBackupInformation -SqlInstance TargetDbServer -Path PathToBackups |
   Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance TargetDbServer -NoRecovery;
```

Note - `PathToBackups` needs to be a path that's relative to the target db server. That is, you can't specify a path on your laptop have it work (the command is running `restore headeronly` on the files found to get the relevant information for all of the files it finds).

For your first time running it, I'd suggest specifying the `OutputScriptOnly` parameter to the Restore-DbaDatabase command so you can see what restore commands it's going to run. Also, I tend to specify the `NoRecovery` parameter out of habit (leaving me to run `restore database TargetDb with recovery;` by hand if that's the right thing to do or leave it in recovery for things like adding a replica to an availability group).

---

Even though you said "no lectures" regarding putting multiple backups into a single file, I will say that that is a non-standard configuration based on over 15 years of experience and it's likely to bite you at some point. Unless you're in an environment where you're charged a fee for each file you create, I'd suggest creating one file (or more! you can stripe large backups over multiple files) per backup. If it's a matter of automation, take a look at the Ola Hallengren backup solution. Also open source.

Comment: Never tried, but can you not do `FILE = 1, FILE = 2`

Comment: @Charlieface - If that question is directed at me, I was answering the OP's question of "Is it possible to restore each sequence automatically with a single RESTORE and let SQL server process them in order?". You can certainly manually do `restore ... , file=1'; restore... , file=2; ...` and the OP knows that. But that isn't a single RESTORE statement.

Comment: I didn't mean that, I meant a single statement `RESTORE LOG db from DISK='c:\trans.bak' WITH NORECOVERY, FILE=1, FILE=2;`

Comment: Ooh... interesting! I tried it on a local copy of AdventureWorks. It appears to be valid syntactically, but when I tried it, it complained about a missing LSN (as though I'd missed a log file). When I did the same logical restore chain but specifying each of `file = 1`, `file = 2`, etc as its own `restore log` statement, it worked just fine.

Comment: It looks like it's taking the last one specified.

Comment: Found the docs! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#specifying-a-backup-set *`RESTORE` The default backup set file number is 1. Only one backup-set FILE option is allowed in a RESTORE statement. It is important to specify backup sets in order."* I'm surprised that it's even valid syntax.

Comment: "I'm surprised that it's even valid syntax." - same. I would be surprised in a bad way if I thought I was restoring a plurality of log files and bringing the db through crash recovery only to discover that it had restored only one and I had to start over from the beginning.

Comment: I was thinking of all of the above and trying to reason...  not sure why applying all in order is not a feature. If you think about it, the backup command treats it that way, adds a sequence, so I would expect restore to follow the same logic.  The other issue is that sometimes you may not have all 4 sequences,  log ends after 2nd sequence, now it's time to restore.  If the restore had built-in logic, it would stop at 2.  Now I have the additional overhead of trying to decide how many sequences there are in a log file.  That's very much manual and complex to try to automate.